# Разбивка на модули кода для однооконного приложения Python

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, классы, qt-designer

Создаю приложение. Интерфейс создается в *Qt Designer*.
Все действия будут происходить в одном окне.

Структура следующая.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или более развернуто:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из меню вызывается одна из страниц `stackedWidget`, на которой расположен `tabWidget`. На каждой вкладке `tabWidget` расположены поля для ввода/вывода информации и кнопки, а так же кнопка для печати отчета в pdf. 
По сути каждая вкладка это самостоятельный расчет. В `tabWidget` они объединены по функциональному признаку.
Для каждой вкладки `tabWidget` получается достаточно большой код программы.

Сейчас у меня создан один класс

```
class MyProgram(QMainWindow):
```

в котором методы описывающие действия на форме: ввод данных, нажатие кнопок.

По задумке хотел каждый расчет (вкладку `tab`) вынести в отдельный модуль (файл). Чтобы было проще ориентироваться в коде и в последствии добавлять новые расчеты.

В настоящий момент написан код для одной вкладки. Не могу понять как разбить код на модули, каким функционалом воспользоваться. 
Возможно ли это технически? Или при данной структуре меню нужно все делать в одном классе и соответственно в одном модуле? 
В какую стороны копать? Читал про наследование и т.п. Картинка в голове не сложилась. Прошу совета.

Минимальный воспроизводимый пример.
Так как минимизировать и воспроизвести несколько тысяч строк кода, что бы было понятно, достаточно трудно. Сделал аналог программы в миниатюре. Вычислительные функции упростил, а идею полностью сохранил.

При запуске имеем начальное окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выборе первого меню (Сложение Вычитание) открывается окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если выбрать вкладку разность:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выборе меню Умножение Деление
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication


class MyProgram(QMainWindow):       
    def __init__(self):             
        super().__init__()  
        uic.loadUi('Form/Test.ui', self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.actionSumDifference.triggered.connect(self.window_sum_difference)      # Выбор меню Сумма Разность
        self.actionWorkDivision.triggered.connect(self.window_work_division)        # Выбор меню Умножение Деление
        self.pushButtonSum.clicked.connect(self.calculation_sum)                    # Кнопка вычисления суммы
        self.pushButtonDifference.clicked.connect(self.calculation_difference)      # Кнопка вычисления разности
        self.pushButtonWork.clicked.connect(self.calculation_work)                  # Кнопка вычисления произведения
        self.pushButtonQuotient.clicked.connect(self.calculation_quotient)          # Кнопка вычисления деления

    def window_sum_difference(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.pageSumDifference)

    def window_work_division(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.pageWorkDivision)

    def calculation_sum(self):
        a = float(self.lineEdiTerm1.text())
        b = float(self.lineEdiTerm2.text())
        s = a + b
        self.lineEditSum.setText(str("%.2f" % s))

    def calculation_difference(self):
        a = float(self.lineEditMinuend.text())
        b = float(self.lineEditSubtrahend.text())
        d = a - b
        self.lineEditDifference.setText(str("%.2f" % d))

    def calculation_work(self):
        a = float(self.lineEditFactor1.text())
        b = float(self.lineEditFactor2.text())
        p = a * b
        self.lineEditWork.setText(str("%.2f" % p))

    def calculation_quotient(self):
        a = float(self.lineEditDividend.text())
        b = float(self.lineEditDivider.text())
        q = a / b
        self.lineEditQuotient.setText(str("%.2f" % q))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyProgram()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вопрос: Как вынести вычисления суммы, разности, произведения и деления каждый в отдельный модуль, если такое возможно?

Не знаю правильно или нет. Как смог получил Test.ui

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 260)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.pageSumDifference = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.pageSumDifference.setObjectName("pageSumDifference")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.pageSumDifference)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.tabWidgeSumDifference = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.pageSumDifference)
        self.tabWidgeSumDifference.setObjectName("tabWidgeSumDifference")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.tab)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.lineEdiTerm1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdiTerm1.setObjectName("lineEdiTerm1")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdiTerm1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.lineEdiTerm2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdiTerm2.setObjectName("lineEdiTerm2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdiTerm2)
        self.pushButtonSum = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButtonSum.setObjectName("pushButtonSum")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.pushButtonSum)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.lineEditSum = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEditSum.setObjectName("lineEditSum")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditSum)
        self.tabWidgeSumDifference.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.formLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.formLayout_2.setObjectName("formLayout_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.lineEditMinuend = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEditMinuend.setObjectName("lineEditMinuend")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditMinuend)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.lineEditSubtrahend = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEditSubtrahend.setObjectName("lineEditSubtrahend")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditSubtrahend)
        self.pushButtonDifference = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButtonDifference.setObjectName("pushButtonDifference")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.pushButtonDifference)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_6)
        self.lineEditDifference = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEditDifference.setObjectName("lineEditDifference")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditDifference)
        self.tabWidgeSumDifference.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.tabWidgeSumDifference, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.pageSumDifference)
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 80, 381, 24))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_13.setFont(font)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.pageWorkDivision = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.pageWorkDivision.setObjectName("pageWorkDivision")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.pageWorkDivision)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.tabWidgeWorkDivision = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.pageWorkDivision)
        self.tabWidgeWorkDivision.setObjectName("tabWidgeWorkDivision")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.formLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.formLayout_3.setObjectName("formLayout_3")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_7)
        self.lineEditFactor1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEditFactor1.setObjectName("lineEditFactor1")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditFactor1)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_8)
        self.lineEditFactor2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEditFactor2.setObjectName("lineEditFactor2")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditFactor2)
        self.pushButtonWork = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButtonWork.setObjectName("pushButtonWork")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.pushButtonWork)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_9)
        self.lineEditWork = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEditWork.setObjectName("lineEditWork")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditWork)
        self.tabWidgeWorkDivision.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.formLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.tab_4)
        self.formLayout_4.setObjectName("formLayout_4")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_4)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_10)
        self.lineEditDividend = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_4)
        self.lineEditDividend.setObjectName("lineEditDividend")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditDividend)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_4)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_11)
        self.lineEditDivider = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_4)
        self.lineEditDivider.setObjectName("lineEditDivider")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditDivider)
        self.pushButtonQuotient = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_4)
        self.pushButtonQuotient.setObjectName("pushButtonQuotient")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.pushButtonQuotient)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_4)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_12)
        self.lineEditQuotient = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_4)
        self.lineEditQuotient.setObjectName("lineEditQuotient")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditQuotient)
        self.tabWidgeWorkDivision.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidgeWorkDivision, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.pageWorkDivision)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionSumDifference = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSumDifference.setObjectName("actionSumDifference")
        self.actionWorkDivision = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionWorkDivision.setObjectName("actionWorkDivision")
        self.menu.addAction(self.actionSumDifference)
        self.menu.addAction(self.actionWorkDivision)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.tabWidgeSumDifference.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.tabWidgeWorkDivision.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Слагаемое 1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Слагаемое 2"))
        self.pushButtonSum.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Расчет"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сумма"))
        self.tabWidgeSumDifference.setTabText(self.tabWidgeSumDifference.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Сумма"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Уменьшаемое"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вычитаемое"))
        self.pushButtonDifference.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Расчет"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Разность"))
        self.tabWidgeSumDifference.setTabText(self.tabWidgeSumDifference.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Разность"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Математическая программка"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Множитель 1"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Множитель 2"))
        self.pushButtonWork.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Расчет"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Произведение"))
        self.tabWidgeWorkDivision.setTabText(self.tabWidgeWorkDivision.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Умножение"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Делимое"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Делитель"))
        self.pushButtonQuotient.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Расчет"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Частное"))
        self.tabWidgeWorkDivision.setTabText(self.tabWidgeWorkDivision.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("MainWindow", "Деление"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Меню"))
        self.actionSumDifference.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сложение Вычитание"))
        self.actionWorkDivision.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Умножение Деление"))
```

Comment: Игорь,  пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] того что вы уже сделали и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать. После этого вам можно будет попробовать дать совет.

Comment: добавьте модуль `Test.ui`

Comment: @S.Nick. Форму в к код я пока не переводил. Если честно еще пока не пробовал это делать. Нужно именно в коде python?

Comment: нет, не python. Добавьте модуль `Test.ui`, который вы получили из Qt Designer.

Comment: Я тут недавно, как можно добавить файл, что-то не могу понять?

Comment: добавлять также как и модуль `main.py`, который содержит класс `MyProgram(QMainWindow)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**q1512096_main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1512096_sum_difference import PageSumDifference
from q1512096_work_division import PageWorkDivision


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):       
    def __init__(self):             
        super().__init__()  
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
        self.label_13.setText("Математическая программка")
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 80, 381, 24))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_13.setFont(font)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)

        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)        
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        
        self.pageSumDifference = PageSumDifference()
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.pageSumDifference) 
        
        self.pageWorkDivision = PageWorkDivision()
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.pageWorkDivision)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(self)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setTitle("Меню")
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionSumDifference = QtWidgets.QAction(self)
        self.actionSumDifference.setObjectName("actionSumDifference")
        self.actionWorkDivision = QtWidgets.QAction(self)
        self.actionWorkDivision.setObjectName("actionWorkDivision")
        self.menu.addAction(self.actionSumDifference)
        self.menu.addAction(self.actionWorkDivision)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.actionSumDifference.setText("Сложение Вычитание")
        self.actionSumDifference.triggered.connect(self.window_sum_difference) 
        self.actionWorkDivision.setText("Умножение Деление")
        self.actionWorkDivision.triggered.connect(self.window_work_division) 

        self.page.setStyleSheet('background-color: #D98;')

    def window_sum_difference(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def window_work_division(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(800, 260)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1512096_sum_difference.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1512096_sum import CalculationAmount
from q1512096_difference import CalculationDifference


class PageSumDifference(QFrame):            
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("pageSumDifference")
        
        self.tabWidgeSumDifference = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabWidgeSumDifference.setObjectName("tabWidgeSumDifference")

        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.tab)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Слагаемое 1", self.tab)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.lineEdiTerm1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdiTerm1.setObjectName("lineEdiTerm1")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdiTerm1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Слагаемое 2", self.tab)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.lineEdiTerm2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdiTerm2.setObjectName("lineEdiTerm2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdiTerm2)
        self.pushButtonSum = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Сумма", self.tab)
        self.pushButtonSum.setObjectName("pushButtonSum")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.pushButtonSum)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Сумма", self.tab)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.lineEditSum = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEditSum.setObjectName("lineEditSum")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditSum)
        self.tabWidgeSumDifference.addTab(self.tab, "Сумма")

        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.formLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.formLayout_2.setObjectName("formLayout_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Уменьшаемое", self.tab_2)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.lineEditMinuend = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEditMinuend.setObjectName("lineEditMinuend")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditMinuend)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Вычитаемое", self.tab_2)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.lineEditSubtrahend = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEditSubtrahend.setObjectName("lineEditSubtrahend")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditSubtrahend)
        self.pushButtonDifference = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Расчет", self.tab_2)
        self.pushButtonDifference.setObjectName("pushButtonDifference")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.pushButtonDifference)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Разность", self.tab_2)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_6)
        self.lineEditDifference = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEditDifference.setObjectName("lineEditDifference")
        self.formLayout_2.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditDifference)
        self.tabWidgeSumDifference.addTab(self.tab_2, "Разность")

        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.tabWidgeSumDifference, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            #pageSumDifference {
                background-color: #D98C00;
            }
            #tab {
                background-color: #8C00D9;
            }
        ''')
        
        self.pushButtonSum.clicked.connect(self.calculation_sum)                    # Кнопка вычисления суммы
        self.pushButtonDifference.clicked.connect(self.calculation_difference)   
        
        self.calculationAmount = CalculationAmount(self)
        self.calculationAmount.hide()
        
        self.calculationDifference = CalculationDifference(self)
        self.calculationDifference.hide()
        
        
    def calculation_sum(self):
        s = self.calculationAmount._sum()
        if not s is None:
            self.lineEditSum.setText(f"{s:.2f}")

    def calculation_difference(self):
        d = self.calculationDifference._difference()
        if not d is None:
            self.lineEditDifference.setText(f"{d:.2f}")
```

**q1512096_sum.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class CalculationAmount(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CalculationAmount, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        
    def _sum(self):
        try:
            a = float(self.parent.lineEdiTerm1.text())
            b = float(self.parent.lineEdiTerm2.text())
            s = a + b
        except:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Введите правильные слагаемые.')
            s = None
        return s
```

**q1512096_difference.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class CalculationDifference(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CalculationDifference, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        
    def _difference(self):
        try:
            a = float(self.parent.lineEditMinuend.text())
            b = float(self.parent.lineEditSubtrahend.text())
            d = a - b
        except:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Введите правильные данные.')
            d = None
        return d
```

**q1512096_work_division.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1512096_multiplication import CalculationMultiplication
from q1512096_divide import CalculationDivide


class PageWorkDivision(QFrame):            
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("pageWorkDivision")
        
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        self.tabWidgeWorkDivision = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabWidgeWorkDivision.setObjectName("tabWidgeWorkDivision")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.formLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.formLayout_3.setObjectName("formLayout_3")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Множитель 1", self.tab_3)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_7)
        self.lineEditFactor1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEditFactor1.setObjectName("lineEditFactor1")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditFactor1)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Множитель 2", self.tab_3)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_8)
        self.lineEditFactor2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEditFactor2.setObjectName("lineEditFactor2")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditFactor2)
        self.pushButtonWork = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Расчет", self.tab_3)
        self.pushButtonWork.setObjectName("pushButtonWork")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.pushButtonWork)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Произведение", self.tab_3)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_9)
        self.lineEditWork = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEditWork.setObjectName("lineEditWork")
        self.formLayout_3.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditWork)
        self.tabWidgeWorkDivision.addTab(self.tab_3, "Умножение")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.formLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.tab_4)
        self.formLayout_4.setObjectName("formLayout_4")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Делимое", self.tab_4)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_10)
        self.lineEditDividend = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_4)
        self.lineEditDividend.setObjectName("lineEditDividend")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditDividend)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Делитель", self.tab_4)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_11)
        self.lineEditDivider = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_4)
        self.lineEditDivider.setObjectName("lineEditDivider")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditDivider)
        self.pushButtonQuotient = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Расчет", self.tab_4)
        self.pushButtonQuotient.setObjectName("pushButtonQuotient")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.pushButtonQuotient)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Частное", self.tab_4)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_12)
        self.lineEditQuotient = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_4)
        self.lineEditQuotient.setObjectName("lineEditQuotient")
        self.formLayout_4.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEditQuotient)
        self.tabWidgeWorkDivision.addTab(self.tab_4, "Деление")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidgeWorkDivision, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pushButtonWork.clicked.connect(self.calculation_work)                  # Кнопка вычисления произведения
        self.pushButtonQuotient.clicked.connect(self.calculation_quotient)     
        
        self.calculationMultiplication = CalculationMultiplication(self)
        self.calculationMultiplication.hide()
        
        self.calculationDivide = CalculationDivide(self)
        self.calculationDivide.hide()

    def calculation_work(self):
        p = self.calculationMultiplication._multiplication()
        if not p is None:
            self.lineEditWork.setText(f"{p:.2f}")    

    def calculation_quotient(self):
        q = self.calculationDivide._divide()
        if not q is None:
            self.lineEditQuotient.setText(f"{q:.2f}")
```

**q1512096_multiplication.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class CalculationMultiplication(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CalculationMultiplication, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        
    def _multiplication(self):
        try:
            a = float(self.parent.lineEditFactor1.text())
            b = float(self.parent.lineEditFactor2.text())
            p = a * b
        except:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Введите правильные данные.')
            p = None
        return p
```

**q1512096_divide.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class CalculationDivide(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CalculationDivide, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        
    def _divide(self):
        try:
            a = float(self.parent.lineEditDividend.text())
            b = float(self.parent.lineEditDivider.text())
            q = a / b
        except:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Введите правильные данные.')
            q = None
        return q
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться. Пока не понял момент для какой цели в отдельные модули вынесены q1512096_sum_difference.py и q1512096_work_division.py. Это для информации, что можно более мелко разбить код или без этого нельзя сделать?

Comment: @ИгорьФедоров , да, это вариант того что можно разбивать код еще на более мелкие модули. Мне показалось, что так приложение будет более читабельнее, но решать вам. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: галочку поставил. С разбивкой разобрался. Попробовал, все работает. Еще один момент. Выражения self.calculationMultiplication.hide(), self.calculationDivide.hide() и т.д. Можно в двух словах, почему без этого не работает? Что мы скрываем?

Comment: @ИгорьФедоров , вы правильно заметили, тут еще надо подумать как лучше сделать или это будет как сейчас `self.calculationDivide = CalculationDivide(self)` с передачей родительского класса (self) и тогда мы его скрыли, чтобы не накрыть ничего в родительском классе. Или сделать модули, которые будут содержать только метод с расчетом и передавать в этот метод значения `self.parent.lineEditDividend.text()` и `self.parent.lineEditDivider.text()` необходимые для расчетов. Думайте, решать вам.

Comment: @ИгорьФедоров , или попробуйте убрать `self.calculationDivide.hide()` и убрать `parent` в строке `super(CalculationDivide, self).__init__()   # parent`

Comment: Еще раз спасибо. Идея понятна, дальше будем импровизировать.

Comment: @ИгорьФедоров пожалуйста.

Comment: Подскажите, не смог понять для какой цели методы  **_divide, _multiplication, _difference и _sum**  в названии начинаются с подчеркивания?

Comment: @ИгорьФедоров , просто так, назовите их как хотите, главное чтобы название метода как-то подсказывало, что в этом методе делается.